# Cant define ES6 arrow functions without context errors

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im new to react and ive got a problem in this class that i cant seem to figure out. Here's my class:

```
  constructor (props) {
          super(props)
    this.state = {
      mapRegion: null,
      hasLocationPermissions: false,
      locationResult: null
    }
  };
    componentDidMount() {
      this._getLocationAsync();
    };
  
    _handleMapRegionChange (mapRegion) {
      console.log(mapRegion);
      this.setState({ mapRegion });
    };
   _getLocationAsync = async () =>  {
  let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
     if (status !== 'granted') {
       this.setState({
         locationResult: 'Permission to access location was denied',
       });
     } else {
       this.setState({ hasLocationPermissions: true });
     }

     let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
     this.setState({ locationResult: JSON.stringify(location) });

     // Center the map on the location we just fetched.
      this.setState({mapRegion: { latitude: location.coords.latitude, longitude: location.coords.longitude, latitudeDelta: 0.0922, longitudeDelta:   0.0421 }});

    }
  render (){
return(
//..render here
)}}
```

Originally, i had tried to make _handleMapRegionChange use ES6 arrows, but had a syntax error that i cant quite figure out, Any help?
Edit: The error im getting is
`TypeError: this.setState is not a function. (In 'this.setState({           mapRegion: mapRegion         })', 'this.setState' is undefined)`

In response to this I attempted to change `_handleMapRegionChange` into an anonymous function like so:

```js
 _handleMapRegionChange = mapRegion => {
    console.log(mapRegion);
    this.setState({ mapRegion });
  };
```

But doing so results in a syntax error:
`Parsing error: Unexpected token =`

I cant quite figure out what i am missing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you have a syntax error, it's helpful to share exactly what it says and what line it points to.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the bad formatting. Im attempting to fix what seems to be a scope error, but cant seem to get the syntax right to make `_handleMapRegionchange` into an anonymous function, Similar to `_getLocationAsync'.

The error im ultimately trying to fix is:
```TypeError: this.setState is not a function. (In 'this.setState({
          mapRegion: mapRegion
        })', 'this.setState' is undefined)```

Comment: Please edit your post to show additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Try catch method inside the _getLocationAsync method to handle the errors, you can console log them inside the catch()

```js
_getLocationAsync = async () => {
    try {
      let {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        this.setState({
          locationResult: 'Permission to access location was denied',
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({hasLocationPermissions: true});
      }
      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      this.setState({locationResult: JSON.stringify(location)});
      // Center the map on the location we just fetched.
      this.setState({
        mapRegion: {
          latitude: location.coords.latitude,
          longitude: location.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  };
```

If not you will get a "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection" error